# Questions about backing up data?

Tags: hard-drive, backup

I have installed a 3TB internal HDD, I have almost more than 2TB of personal data, this drive will be unplugged after backing up.

My question is that I have music production and photography data with millions of files, I want to ask if is it a good option to use different folders with large amounts of data as ISO image files to save a large number of files from getting corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a large number of files into a container is exactly
the opposite of protecting against corruption.

In case of corruption of the container, you will be then be
losing all the files in it, rather than losing just one of
your millions of files.

Also, storing the files into the container might need it to
be rewritten many times, while getting larger all the time.
This means that you will be shortening the lifetime of the
disk while doing extensive rewrites. Writing instead the
individual files one-by-one will do the minimal number of
writes to maximize the disk's lifetime.

As a last remark, there exists only one protection against
corruption, which is having more than one copy of the backup.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: I mean anything like ISO, Zip or similar, as asked.

Answer (score 3):

Putting files into folders will have no effect on whether or not data gets corrupted.  However, it does help in organization, so that is up to you.

That being said, keeping the drive in your computer - even when disconnected - is not the best choice.  If the computer gets stolen, catches on fire, you forget to disconnect the drive and do something bad...  I would recommend getting an external dock for the drive. Then you can put the drive somewhere else as needed.  Spending a few extra dollars now can save you spending a whole lot more down the line.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways you can look at this, but the answer is always going to be: don't rely on a single backup if the data is that important.

Now to answer your question in more detail.

A harddisk is made platters and data is stored binary on the platters. Files are arranged on the disk in sequence and a table places their start and endpoint on the disk.

When a file is retrieved, the index is checked, and then the data is read from the platters. If all is succesful, the file will be loaded into memory in order to be accessed.

If data corruption occurs its possible that some of the bytes of a file cannot be read anymore. On a small file this can mean that this file in particular cannot be accessed anymore. If you have an ISO file however, it can mean that a single corruption can corrupt the entire ISO, which won't just hurt a single file, but everything in the collection.

With some files, a file can still be read with the corruption present and it is just being skipped with some glitches. This is often preferred over losing the entire file.

With an ISO you just lose everything inside.

So no, if you want to store data and make sure it remains the best quality over time, the less it is placed inside containers, the better.

That said, you should have at least 2 different backups, preferably more. Also keep in mind that a harddisk has a lifespan of about 20 years. After that, many different things can fail, including the controller present on the disk itself. If the controller dies, the entire harddisk cannot be read from anymore, even if the platters don't contain any errors. In that case it does not matter how you store it.